# Installing PHPMailer with Composer

Tags: php, apache, composer-php, phpmailer

I feel like I am almost there. (I could be wrong though)

from the root of my apache server (/usr/local/var/www)

I ran

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

I've now got the folder system

```
/usr/local/var/www/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer
```

In this folder, there is a `src` folder, and in that folder are basically all the files I think I need to include on the php page where I want to use PHPmailer.

On the PHP page where I want to use PHPMailer, I have at the top:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```

and in the page I am calling

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); //Argument true in constructor enables exceptions
```

I am getting an error message

```
Error: Class "PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer" not found in /usr/local/var/www/xxx.php
```

It seems like something isn't linking up correctly.

Comment: You need to source composer's autoloader, typically via something like `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';`.

Comment: Add the three lines:  `require './Exception.php'; require './PHPMailer.php'; require './SMTP.php';`  **after** the line `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;` (change to the actual path for the 3 files please) , retry and see what happens

Answer (score 2):

[Alex Howansky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453002/alex-howansky) posted [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70718016/installing-phpmailer-with-composer/70718654#comment125017987_70718016):

> You need to source composer's autoloader, typically via something like `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';`.

[Ken Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11854986/ken-lee) [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70718016/installing-phpmailer-with-composer/70718654#comment125018510_70718016):

> Add the three lines: `require './Exception.php'; require './PHPMailer.php'; require './SMTP.php';` after the line `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;` (change to the actual path for the 3 files please) , retry and see what happens

Both suggestions fixed the problem. I'm going with the vendor/autoload.php solution.